# How do I open a quickfix result in a new buffer?

Tags: buffers, quickfix

When I have the quickfix window open (e.g. from `:grep foo<cr>:cw`) I can go to the window and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> and it will open the file under the cursor in an existing buffer.

Is there a way to open it in a new buffer, besides `:split` and then going to the quickfix window?

Comment: When you say buffer, I believe you mean window.

Comment: @tommcdo I think I mean both :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

see `switchbuf` option, see:

`:h switchbuf`

you may setup switchbuf as:

`set switchbuf=useopen,split`